# Compile time validation of method arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, validation

I've found some similar questions here, but the incomplete answers didn't help and produced more confusion than clarifying anything, so here's my try to give a more structured question and get hopefully answers that will help more users.

**My simplified example**: I have a Java class with two different constructors

```
public class ObjectOfInterest {
  public ObjectOfInterest(String string, Integer int) { ... }
  public ObjectOfInterest(String string1, String string2) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I need some compile time validation on the calls of these constructors. The parameter `string2` has to be some literal, and I want to mark the calls as warning depending on the content (i.e. give a warning, when it's no literal or when the literal has not the correct format).

Unfortunately documentation for validation in Java with Eclipse isn't easy to understand, sometimes outdated, most often it seems to me incomplete, and it seems that there's no working example out there that's short enough to be used in a tutorial.

**My goal**:
First step: I'd like to have a validator that marks calls of that two parameter version with a warning - just to get started somewhere and get to understand the basics.

**What I've found so far**:
The few examples I've seen make a `public class MyValidator implements IValidator, ISourceValidator` where `IValidator` needs to implement a method `public void validate(IValidationContext arg0, IReporter arg1) throws ValidationException` and seem to be from an old version of the validation framework (sometimes I found just empty method with comment *useless*), and `ISourceValidator` needs to implement a method `public void validate(IRegion arg0, IValidationContext arg1, IReporter arg2)` - this seems to be the more up to date version.

Then you have to add some extension points to some `plugin.xml` (I'm not totally clear where this plugin.xml is).

**Where I stab in the dark**: it's totally unclear how to work with `IRegion`, `IValidationContext`, and `IReporter` - maybe I'm on the totally wrong way, but what do I get here? How to find calls of that constructor within validation?

I'd extend this question after the first steps get more clear. Outlook, I'll want to add the possibility of quick fixes to the two String version of the constructor and manipulate the code this way - but that's at least two steps ahead, details coming later.

Comment: Just for the record: if you have two unrelated constructors, then chances are that your class is violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Is your goal improving code, or to write an eclipse plugin? Because "compile time validation" is basically the Java type system, i.e. Classes. If you want constraints on your parameters, define a proper class for them, instead of tacking on some IDE support.

Comment: Why not use an existing open-source eclipse plugin that shows compile-time warnings, as a guide?

Comment: You can use pmd (https://pmd.github.io/). However i believe you can add your validation check at the startup of your application. In your case you can use `Java Reflection Api` for validation checkup. Most famous frameworks (such spring, hibernate) always doing this process to validate the application logic.

Comment: I believe this is not a good approach to tackle it in this way. Specifically, validation that would check if string is some literal is not useful, because if it's supposed to be a specific set of literals, then it should be an enumeration (and no extra compile-time checking is required), and if it's supposed to have some specific format, then most likely such format should be extracted into its own class and properly documented (again, no compile time checking required other than what's already in javac).

Comment: @GhostCat - it was just to simplify the context - I just wanted to say there are more than one constructor and I want to take care of the parameters of one of them

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni - in fact I AM using Java Reflection Api, that's the reason why I want to check the parameter of the method and the goal is not checking at startup / runtime, but at compile time (the application is way too huge to check all usages at startup)

Comment: @RobertBräutigam, M.Prokhorov - the goal is validating the code - there's a common principle in the parameters allowed that shouldn't be too difficult to check at compile time, but it's way too many to enumerate them and there are some dependencies that I could not put in a simple class or enumeration - so therefore writing a validator

Comment: @RealSkeptic - do you have a suggestion for a simple plugin working on java code? I'd be happy to find something small enough to take as a guide

Comment: Well, I don't know how simple it is or not, but you can try the [Unnecessary Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/).

Comment: What do you mean by literal? Is `new ObjectOfInterest(SOME_VALUE, 5)` acceptable, if `SOME_VALUE` is a `private static final` field?

Comment: @biziclop - in my setting it's really "some literal" - in practice anything that can be analyzed at compile time would do - but I guess it's easier to analyze "some literal" than checking first if a member is static final or whatever

Comment: Okay, that helps a bit. So basically you want to validate your input, but at compile time? Wouldn't simply creating a class that wraps a string and simply doesn't allow an invalid value to be created work? There are very few things on this level that you can't express with the Java type system one way or another.

Comment: @biziclop - the literals will be used in a reflection api setting, so I rather want to check once at compile time and make sure everything will work than testing at runtime similar things a thousand times again and again, slowing down stuff unnecessarily - the usefullness of that old design decision can't be discussed here - the million LOC are simply there and cannot be changed in a week or two.

Comment: So what kind of validation would you do? Would you check that the method name in the string exists? Because in that case you can do the opposite and generate a class at compile time that contains a constant for every valid name. Or something similar. Failing that, another option is to plug into a byte code analysing tool, something like FindBugs.

Comment: @biziclop - it's a bit more complicated, I'll have to check if a member in a certain class exists (and if it has a getter with the same name) - of course I could optimize the code in some way, make it nicer, generate constants, and so on - the point is, it will take tooo long. The cheapest thing that will provide what's needed is some check at compile time - or some check like FindBugs or SonarQube would also do - I'm not sure what's easier to implement.

Comment: @outofmind It's definitely worth taking a look at writing a custom FindBugs detector then.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - thanks for the suggestion, but source code of that one is still 500 kB and it seems to use other concepts - at least IValidator or ISourceValidator isn't even used once - as source code isn't documented, it's not really usable as a guide, would have been a good idea, though

Comment: I came here searching for a solution to this ques, but now I also think that it's not required. As other's have pointed out, the class type should be able to reign things. And for mandatory fields, create constructors so they can't be null. At the end the user of method also has to follow contract of method. If a user passes null to a not null param then it is bound to give errors. We don't have to null check everything and define a boundary in project for validations.

Answer (score 3):

First I have to say that what you are trying to **goes beyond normal Java programming**. There is no normal way do validation at compile time, except what can be achieved using normal types.

What you want to do also **goes beyond what can be done using annotation processors**. Annotation processors are kind of semi-normal, in that they are standardised and a part of the Java framework. They are classes that are run during compilation, they get as input the *signature* of classes and methods, and can be used for validation and code generation.

If you still what to do this **there are abnormal ways**, however:

---

#### Eclipse Plug-in Solution

The solution you seem to be trying is to write an Eclipse plug-in that uses the Eclipse Java tools to do validation. That should work, I don't know how easy it will be, and the validation will only work for users who are using Eclipse.

---

#### Checker Solution

The tool which seems best according to my (limited) knowledge is this:

The **[Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/)** for static analysis.

It is used for exactly the kind of things that you want to do. It seems reasonably well-documented and easy to set up. It is used for example for doing nullness analysis and compile time validation of regex syntax. There is a [tutorial](https://checkerframework.org/tutorial/webpages/encryption-checker-cmd.html) which sounds pretty similar to your thing. There is a chapter in the manual on [creating a new checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker).

It would probably take a lot of time and effort to make a solution using this, but I also think it seems very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:**
>
> **This may not the exact solution. But I am trying to discuss**
>   **possible methods to work around the problem. I have mentioned**
>   **alternative methods which may help to work. Please join for the**
>   **discussion.**

I would like to try with **Java Annotation Processors** which introduced in `JDK-5` and standardized in `JDK-6` under `JSR-269` specifications.

It's required to annotate files (java `@interfaces`) which should validate according to the rules using a custom annotation. If it's not possible to annotate each file, it will have to annotate the package that contain classes to be validated (it's possible to iterate through inner packages also). Following example will demonstrate how to validate classes using annotated classes and annotation processors. I have uploaded sample project into a github repository. Please view project repository on github https://github.com/hjchanna/compile_validation_java

**STEP 01: create an annotation interface (`@interface`)**

```
package com.mac.compile_validation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * @author hjchanna
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CompileValidation {

}
```

**STEP 02: create a `Processor` class, which introduces compile validation rules to the compiler**

The processor class should `extend` from `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` and it should be annotated with `@SupportedAnnotationTypes` and `@SupportedSourceVersion` annotations. Please modify the `CompileValidationProcessor` class according to the exact requirement or validation rules.

```
package com.mac.compile_validation;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror;
import javax.lang.model.util.ElementFilter;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

/**
 *
 * @author hjchanna
 */
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.mac.compile_validation.CompileValidation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class CompileValidationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    /**
     * Processes a set of annotation types on type elements originating from the
     * prior round and returns whether or not these annotation types are claimed
     * by this processor. If {@code
     * true} is returned, the annotation types are claimed and subsequent
     * processors will not be asked to process them; if {@code false} is
     * returned, the annotation types are unclaimed and subsequent processors
     * may be asked to process them. A processor may always return the same
     * boolean value or may vary the result based on chosen criteria.
     *
     * The input set will be empty if the processor supports {@code
     * "*"} and the root elements have no annotations. A {@code
     * Processor} must gracefully handle an empty set of annotations.
     *
     * @param annotations the annotation types requested to be processed
     * @param roundEnv environment for information about the current and prior
     * round
     * @return whether or not the set of annotation types are claimed by this
     * processor
     */
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        //Iterate through compiling files which annotated with @CompileValidation
        for (Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CompileValidation.class)) {
            //find type element for element
            TypeElement typeElement = findEnclosingTypeElement(elem);

            //required parameter types
            TypeElement stringType = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("java.lang.String");
            TypeElement integerType = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("java.lang.Integer");

            //find construtors according to your scenario
            ExecutableElement conA = findConstructor(typeElement, stringType.asType(), integerType.asType());
            ExecutableElement conB = findConstructor(typeElement, stringType.asType(), stringType.asType());

            //check availability of constructors, if not available it should show a warning message in compile time
            if (conA == null || conB == null) {
                String message = "Type " + typeElement + " has malformed constructors.";
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING, message);
            }

        }
        return true; // no further processing of this annotation type
    }

    /**
     * Returns a constructor which have two parameters and parameter types equal
     * to paramA and paramB. Return null if required constructor is not
     * available.
     *
     * @param typeElement like the class which may constructors encapsulated
     * @param paramA first parameter of required constructor
     * @param paramB second parameter of required constructor
     * @return constructor which have required parameters
     */
    private static ExecutableElement findConstructor(TypeElement typeElement, TypeMirror paramA, TypeMirror paramB) {
        List<ExecutableElement> executableElements = ElementFilter.constructorsIn(typeElement.getEnclosedElements());

        for (ExecutableElement executableElement : executableElements) {
            List<VariableElement> variableElements = (List<VariableElement>) executableElement.getParameters();

            //match constructor params and length
            if (variableElements.size() == 2
                    && variableElements.get(0).asType().equals(paramA)
                    && variableElements.get(1).asType().equals(paramB)) {
                return executableElement;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the TypeElement of element e.
     *
     * @param e Element which contain TypeElement
     * @return Type element
     */
    public static TypeElement findEnclosingTypeElement(Element e) {
        while (e != null && !(e instanceof TypeElement)) {
            e = e.getEnclosingElement();
        }

        return TypeElement.class.cast(e);
    }
}
```

**STEP 03: create processing service link file**

Then it's required to add a class with name `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` into the resource path of the project (`/src/main/resources/META-INF/services`). The file contains only class name of the `Processor`. According to previous example the configuration file content as follows.

```
com.mac.compile_validation.CompileValidationProcessor
```

Previous method is applicable to maven projects. It's possible to inject the configuration file manually into the `META-INF/services` folder of output `.jar` file if needed.

**STEP 04: disable validation for the current project**

Disable annotation processing for current project. If it is enabled, it will fail to build current project since the compiler try to locate the `Processor` class to validate. But it's still not compiled. So it will fail to build the project because of itself. Add following code to the `pom.xml` (inside `<build> -> <plugin>`).

```
<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
```

---

> **It's now almost finished. Only thing have to do further is adding build output `.jar` file dependency into the original project.**

It's time to test the project. Annotate required classes with custom annotation which created previously (`CompileValidation`). It will show a warning if it's fail to validate annotated classes. My output as follows.

[image: build output]

> **ALTERNATIVE SOLUTIONS**

- It's possible to use **`PMD`**, which is a java source code scanner. It provides ways to define rules using xml configuration.
- Try to validate classes using java reflection when it boots up. (this is not what you asked. but it is a good practice to validate stuff before start working as spring, hibernate and other reputed frameworks do.)
- Try **`Java Instrumentation API`**, but only possible reaction is crashing the application if it violated the rule. It's not a good practice.

Comment: If I'm not terribly mistaken this solution validates the format of the *declaration* of the constructors, not the *calls* to the constructors. And validating the calls is what this question is about. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to inspect the body of methods using annotation processors, so I don't think it is possible to solve the problem using this approach.